# Short story with ship and ancient artifact

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Someone receives an artifact which is the model of a ship. He immediately is teleported on top of the ship which becomes life-size and drops in a large ocean. There are two sides in the ocean, one which represents males and one which represents females.

I read this maybe 10 years ago, but I think it was from the 1930s or so.

Since most of what I read is Asimov or Bradbury, we can probably assume that it was one of those two.

## Edit

It probably wasn't either of the two because, as @M.A.Golding pointed out, their first stories came from the end of the 1930s. Good catch!

Comment: A story published in the 1930s or so would have a low probability of being written by Asimov or Bradbury. Isaac Asimov (1920-1992) had his first stories published in 1939.  Ray Bradbury (1920-2012) also had his first stories published in 1939.  Knowing anything about their biographies would have made you realize a story from about the 1930 was probably not by either of them.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Good point. Sorry about the confusion!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like *[The Ship of Ishtar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ship_of_Ishtar)* by A. Merritt

> The archaeologist hero, Kenton, receives a mysterious ancient
>   Babylonian artifact, which he discovers contains an incredibly
>   detailed model of a ship. A dizzy spell casts Kenton onto the deck of
>   the ship, which becomes a full-sized vessel sailing an eternal sea. At
>   one end is Sharane the assistant priestess of Ishtar and her female
>   minions, and at the other is Klaneth the assistant priest of Nergal
>   and his male minions, representatives of two opposed deities. None of
>   them can cross an invisible barrier at the midline of the ship, but
>   Kenton can. His arrival destabilizes a situation that had been frozen
>   for 6,000 years, and fantastic adventures ensue.

Comment: Seems like this is it! I'll wait for a while so you can get more upvotes before I accept it.